# How to connect to another mysql server using mysql_connect

Tags: mysql-connect

is it possible to connect to another mysql server using mysql_connect function?

this is my code

```
$dbHost = "192.168.1.2:3306";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "pass";

$con = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

and i got this mysql error

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.9' (using password: YES)

Comment: If you are connecting to 192.168.1.2 then why you are getting error from 192.168.1.9? also make sure you can access mysql from console.

Comment: 192.168.1.9 is the ip address of my router